# Standard way to bulk crud image with caption in an API?

Tags: api, api-design, conventions

I am trying to build a API for doing CRUD on images with their caption. So far I can think of 
option1: sending the images in form-data as list of images and their corresponding captions in another list and map them according the list index. Cons: mapping according to index may lead to human error and seems somehow inconsistent.

option2: sending the images converted to base64 string and sending them in json. Cons: increases the file size to 33%.

can someone with similar experience shed some light on this. Thanks in Advance.